# dnsutils installation error on Raspberry Pi

Tags: apt, software-installation, raspberry-pi, dns

I am trying to install dnsutils on a Raspberry Pi via

```
sudo apt-get install dnsutils
```

and I get the following error messages:

```
Err:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf libirs161 armhf 1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1+deb10u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian buster/main armhf dnsutils armhf 1:9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1+deb10u1
  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/b/bind9/libirs161_9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1+deb10u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/b/bind9/dnsutils_9.11.5.P4+dfsg-5.1+deb10u1_armhf.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

For some reason it's not able to find the files. I am not sure of anyone else having this issue on a Raspberry Pi, and I am not sure how else I can install it. Any suggestions?

Comment: So, did you run "apt-get update"?

Comment: The problem was that "apt-get update" was not working because the repo changed versions. I think that it said that it change from "stable" to "oldstable". I needed to explicitly accept the update before "apt-get update" worked. Then, I needed to upgrade.

Comment: Maybe leave more details about your configuration and what you did before the problem occurred.

Comment: @U.Windl problem was that he didn't do what the programs told him to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the repo changed versions. The update needed to be explicitly accepted before `apt-get update` worked. The command to accept the change was

```
sudo apt-get update --allow-releaseinfo-change
```

To apply the change, the repo needed to be upgraded by

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then, `dnsutils` was installed successfully by

```
sudo apt-get install dnsutils
```